# VideoView doesn't start inside onPrepared

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I have tried so many answer but there is no success. I want to play video after it loaded from remote `URL`. What is frustrating is `Toast` is showing  but 
video doesn't play.

**Code**

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            Log.i(TAG,"onPrepared");
            new  Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    videoView.start();
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"start video",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },100);
        }
    });
```

**xml**

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/video_view"
    android:layout_width="410dp"
    android:layout_height="307.50dp"
 />
```

Comment: may be problem is with your url try this url and check it is working or not.... http://videocdn.bodybuilding.com/video/mp4/62000/62792m.mp4

Comment: still not working!